# Query ascending by the NSDate field of pointer

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have 2 Classes: Event and Participant. Here are their attributes.

Event:

- NSDate   startingDate
- NSString title

Participant:

- PFUser   user
- Event    event
- and some other attributes I'll need later

When a user want to participate on event I create Participant object and assign event to it and also user. Later on I want to get all the Events that have Participants for current user. And this events need to be ordered by startingDate ascending.

I created a query that gets all the participants for current user, and the I read the event addribute from it, but I really need that events will be ordered by its starting date. How should I approach this. I created Participant class because I need to save the data that user create for this event.

**EDIT:** I tried this one:

```
PFQuery *eventQuery = [Event query];
[eventQuery orderByAscending:@"startingDate"];

PFQuery *participantQuery = [Participant query];
[participantQuery includeKey:@"user"];
[participantQuery includeKey:@"event"];
[participantQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser];
[participantQuery whereKey:@"event" matchesQuery:eventQuery];
[participantQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray *eventsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (Participant *participant in objects) {
        [eventsArray addObject:participant.event];
    }
}];

here I can use eventsArray
```

But this one just ignores the `[eventQuery orderByAscending:@"startingDate"];` line. I also need to ask for opinion that I choose the approach to first fetch the Participants and then put them in a for loop to get their events and saves them in an array. Is this good? It seems wrong, why do I need to fetch participant if I acctualy need Events for User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Event class had a reference to the Participant class (either as `Array` or `Relation<Participant>` depending on size) named `participants`, then you could do something like the following:

```
PFQuery *eventQuery = [Event query];

PFQuery *participantQuery = [Participant query];
[participantQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[eventQuery whereKey:@"participants" matchesQuery:participantQuery];
[eventQuery orderByAscending:@"startingDate"];
[eventQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // objects array contains your Event objects
}];
```

You just need to update your code that creates `Participant` objects to also add it to the `participants` column of the `Event` object.

Comment: I already have the relation to named participants and if I look on parse the participant are saved in this relation. But this query dont work. The console in xcode tell me **Error: bad type for $inQuery** I think that it has something to do with this line `[eventQuery whereKey:@"participants" matchesQuery:participantQuery];` Maybe you can't mathes query on relation. Can somebody confirm that.

Comment: I use this type of query to check if a user is in the `users` relation on the `Role` class all the time (i.e. is this use in the Admin role). It works fine. Check that your `participants` column is of type `Relation<Participant>` (look at the column header in the data browser). The error is stating that the column type and the type of the object you're comparing to don't match.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was shure that I made everything right, but I checked again and I realized that I changed the name of the relations attribute. I'll try this method and if everything will work out well I'll selectry your answer as a correct solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to order your Participant objects to order them locally after the fetch. Use `sortUsingDescriptors:` on the `NSMutableArray`.

Try this:

```
PFQuery *participantQuery = [Participant query];
[participantQuery includeKey:@"user"];
[participantQuery includeKey:@"event"];
[participantQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser];
[participantQuery whereKey:@"event" matchesQuery:eventQuery];
[participantQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray *eventsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"event.startingDate" ascending:YES],nil];
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [eventsArray sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
}];
```

(Note the use of the dot notation on the descriptor to get the property of a property - in this case, the startingDate property on the event property.)

Comment: This was my plan B. The only issue is that if there are more than 1000 events I can fetch only 1000 of them (parse limitation) and in that way there is a chance that some of the events that should be present first are missing in the array.

Comment: Ok I accept this for an answer. It works for most of the scenarios. Thansk